# What is the best way to match elements by index for update in a Scatter plot?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using [d3.v3.min.js](http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js) and the example [D3 Zoomable Plot](http://bl.ocks.org/peterssonjonas/4a0e7cb8d23231243e0e) as reference I built a scatter plot. The most relevant bits are:

```
var svg = d3.select("#scatter1")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", outerWidth)
    .attr("height", outerHeight)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + (width + margin.left + margin.right) + " " + (height + margin.top + margin.bottom))
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

var objects = svg.append("svg")
    .classed("objects", true)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

objects.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(values)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .classed("dot", true)
    .attr("r", function (d) {
        return 6 * Math.sqrt(2.0 / Math.PI);
    })
    .attr("transform", transform)
    .style("fill", colorVal);
```

and some needed css:

```
.dot {
  fill-opacity: .5;
}

.dotHidden {
  fill-opacity: .1;
}
```

My data values are defined as:

```
var values = [[x0, y0], [x1, y1], ....];
```

with a custom property `idx` per element i.e.

```
values[i].idx === i
```

Now I'd like to highlight only a subset of the dot elements, namely only those that are in an indexes list e.g. `selectedIdx = [4, 8, 10, 38, 90]`. How can I do that in the fastest possible way? is there an d3 js idiomatic way to do it? I have attempted to do this below and it does the job to "hide" all the dots but I actually want to hide only the ones not in the `selectedIdx`.

```
d3.select("#scatter1 svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .attr("class", "dotHidden");
```

**UPDATE:** This is a follow up of the question [How to get the index of the data element in a histogram on mouseover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323453/how-to-get-the-index-of-the-data-element-in-a-histogram-on-mouseover)

Comment: You can filter the elements not selected like this: 
 `d3.select("#scatter1 svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .filter(function(d, i){
    return selectedIdx.indexOf(i) === -1;
  }).attr("class", "dotHidden");`
(You can also use a dictionary for the selectedIdx to avoid indexOf(i)) or instead of using i, use d.idx if that fits better.

Comment: Yes that's a way to do it but not very elegant. Is there a way to directly select only those circles that ocurr in the `selectedIdx` array?

Comment: You can use a tertiary operator with indexOf. However, if you don't provide a [MCVE] we can test, it'd be difficult to get a proper solution. Also, have in mind that *elegant* is quite opinion-based.

Comment: @altocumulus Yep good detective work! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`classed`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_classed). You need to cycle through all elements only once, then. Plus your code gets more robust because you make sure that `dotHidden` class is unset for all circles in `selectIdx`.

```
d3.select("#scatter1 svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .classed("dotHidden", function(d, i) {
    return selectIdx.indexOf(i) === -1;
  });
```

If you‘re running ES2015 or use a transpiler you can improve the callback:

```
.classed("dotHidden", (d, i) => selectIdx.indexOf(i) === -1);
```

Comment: Good but I wanted something better than `indexOf`I believe there should be a way to tell D3 JS (idiomatically) that I am updating some circles even if having to compute the set difference first.

Comment: Ah, I see. I suppose  `selectIdx` changes over time by some user intreaction while the complete data set (`values`?) doesn‘t - is that right?

Comment: Correct! this is a one way interaction between a histogram (all points inside a bin) and two scatter plots to "highlight" which points belong to the histogram bin.

Comment: A slightly faster version using http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf is `.filter(function(d, i){return _.indexOf(selectedIdx, i, true) === -1; })` namely it does a binary search i.e. O(n log n) and not a linear search ending in O(n^2), now I am just looking whether I always get the selectedIdx sorted or was mere coincidence ...

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the selected data (not the indexes) you can use data binding capabilities of d3.js, in particular [`selection.exit()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_exit):

```
d3.select("#scatter1 svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  // make sure to reset all circles to normal
  .classed("dotHidden", false);  
  .data(selectedValues)
  // narrow selection to values that are not in selectedValues
  .exit()
  .classed("dotHidden", true);
```

Comment: I believe there is possibility to pass a second parameter to `.data(selectedValues)`i.e. the keys to match and using the indexes there would make a faster much more efficient solution than matching by arrays of Double values ...

Comment: You could in fact define a key function that sets a nonexisting key for every datum not in `selectIdx`, exit selection would be filled with them. Still I‘m 
not sure how you want to avoid calling `selectIdx.indexOf()`, you could IMO just shift it around.